# Trigger javascript function when any of multiple fields change (onchange)

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

I have a basic JS knowledge.

I need to trigger the function below when any of the fields change in a from. Here it works only when the var2 changes but I need it to be triggered when any of the var# will change. (I will have 30 var at the end in the form)

I think I need to have an OR condition, "if (var1.onchange OR var2.onchange OR ...) function()"

Thanks in advance for your valuable input!

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var var0 = document.getElementById('field09')
    var1 = document.getElementById('field10')
    var2 = document.getElementById('field11')
    storage = document.getElementById('field12')

var2.onchange= function()


  { 
storage.value = var0.value+" ; "+var1.value+" ; "+var2.value;
};
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var var0 = document.getElementById('field09'),
        var1 = document.getElementById('field10'),
        var2 = document.getElementById('field11'),
        storage = document.getElementById('field12'),

        trigFunc = function(){ 
            storage.value = var0.value + " ; " + var1.value + " ; " + var2.value;
        }

    var0.onchange = trigFunc;
    var1.onchange = trigFunc;
    var2.onchange = trigFunc;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/Wm2nb)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but it doesn't trigger the function. I don't get the field storage populated.

Comment: Put the binding statements in the below the function definition. See your own code here: http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/Wm2nb/

Comment: If you want that the function be triggered immediately after any user input, use event `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`